# How to resize BufferedImage but conserve it's Graphics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I have my own custom control which maintains backing image for it's content. This buffer is of type `BufferedImage`.

**ATTENTION! The usage of backing image is due to requirements. Don't teach me to draw within `paintComponent()`**

Currently I am resizing image in the following way:

```
@Override
public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    if( bufferedImage == null ) {
        bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }
    else {
        if( bufferedImage.getWidth() < width || bufferedImage.getHeight() < height ) {
            BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            newImage.createGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
            bufferedImage = newImage;
        }
    }
    super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
}
```

unfortunately, this requires to create new `BufferedImage` object and hence makes previously obtained `Graphics` object invalid.

So I have to have my own method

```
public Graphics2D createImageGraphics() {
    if( bufferedImage != null ) {
        return bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

although I would like to override `getGraphics()`.

Is it possible to resize image so that it conserve Graphics object?

Comment: Any reason for maintaining your own buffer while Swing already provides double-buffering?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Guillaume how to activate it?

Comment: It's active by default. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: It doesn't. By the matter of fact. See my update.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet, update ready

Comment: `panel.getGraphics().drawOval(0, 0, 100, 100);`--> never use `getGraphics()`. Instead, override `paintComponent` use the graphics parameter of that method. Whenever you want to update/refresh the display, call `repaint()`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet you told Swing has buffer by default. You forgot it? Now you see you were wrong? If Swing would have buffer by default, there were no reason to redraw picture each time. Since it has no buffer by default, one should either redraw picture each time, or implement buffer himself. I think question about reasons is closed now and we can finally turn to initial question.

Comment: Am am removing sample proving there is no buffering in Swing in order not to distract attention from the main topic.

Comment: @SuzanCioc I am definitely not wrong. Double-buffering means that you won't see each step of drawing and instead you will see an instant drawing of whatever you are drawing. Anyway, this is the correct way to do things in Swing. Drawing a buffered image every times a repaint() is request is actually less efficient and mainly useless

Comment: @SuzanCioc You are absolutely not proving that there is no buffering in Swing.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I know what double buffering is. This doesn't matter, you are trying to change the topic.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet don't mix double buffering and backing image I have. Don't change the topic please.

Comment: I am not changing the subject neither mixing a backing image and double buffer. Please be clearer in what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to resize `BufferedImage` while keeping it's previously obtained `Graphics` valid. This is written in the question.

Comment: @SuzanCioc What are you trying to achieve by doing that? Improve performance? Remove visual glitches? I am just asking because it is likely that there are already built-in ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet my drawing algorithm is time consuming, it lasts many seconds. I can't put in into `paintComponent`. I want drawing to continue while window moving and resizing.

Answer (score -1):

Here is small example of how you perform custom painting in Swing:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JFrameTest {

    private boolean drawOval = false;

    protected void initUI() {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if (drawOval) {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g.drawOval(0, 0, 100, 100);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, 100);
            }
        };

        AbstractAction drawAction = new AbstractAction("Draw") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawOval = true;
                panel.repaint();
            }
        };

        JButton drawButton = new JButton(drawAction);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(drawButton);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JFrameTest().initUI();
            }
        });

    }
}
```